# Does Umbraco CMS has got option to change language?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, polish

I would like to use Umbraco CMS. But I need to know is there availible changing admin User Interface language to Polish? So that the whole admin stuff and everything would be in Polish language.

I don't need Multi-Language functionality.

I know that there are availible other language packs (like German), so is there also Polish language pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Polish is available out of the box in the umbraco backoffice. I don't know what the quality of the translation is though, so you'll have to have a look at that yourself.

Comment: Could you give me a link or something? I was looking in backoffice but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I have found it under users -> users. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should've said that it's a setting that can be changed for each user. :-) By the way, if you have more questions: you will get faster and better answers at [Our Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org) than on SO, most of the community goes there.